# rspec feature test not finding modal input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a rspec test that is trying to fill in a field in pop up modal form. The relevant line is

```
fill_in 'Name', with: 'Jo Blo'
```

and the error message is

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible field "Name" that is not disabled
```

which implies it is finding the field but sees it as disabled. However, if I use the capybara-screenshot to view the page at the time of failure, the field is visible and the html for the field is

```
<div class="field">
        <label for="user_name">Name</label><sup>*</sup><br>
        <input type="text" name="user[name]" id="user_name">
</div>
```

i.e it is  not disabled.
The field is in a `div#modal_new_user`. If I change the test to

```
expect(page).to have_css '#modal_new_user'
fill_in 'Name', with: 'Jo Blo'
```

the error message becomes

```
    Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_css '#modal_new_user'
           expected to find visible css "#modal_new_user" but there were no 

matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

Which seems to imply the modal is not being found, but again, if I look a the capybara screenshot, the html for the modal is visible.
How do I fix this?

I am using capybara 3.0.2 and rspec-rails 3.7.2.

The code for bootstrap modal is

```
 <div id='modal_new_user' class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Warning</h4>
          <p>enter code here Right now there is a 10 day free trial. Just fill in the form below.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="edit_user" id="edit_user_12004" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="306T/5kB9pqb9sW6mdW+tXyCzfydEF2tf8wQMJXEICO5uQ/YEDVVYqg12l7Qe+lU4uELZy/d1VIhzZObk/FVcQ==" />

      <div class="field">
        <label for="user_name">Name</label><sup>*</sup><br />
        <input type="text" name="user[name]" id="user_name" />
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label for="user_email">Email</label><sup>*</sup><br />
        <input type="email" name="user[email]" id="user_email" />
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label for="user_password">Password</label><sup>*</sup><br />
        <input type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password" />
      </div>

      <p id="terms">By creating your account, you are agreeing to the site <a target="_blank" href="/legal">Terms and Conditions</a>.  You will not be spammed, we dislike spam as much as you do.
      </p>
      <input type="hidden" value="clubs#edit" name="user[referral]" id="user_referral" />
      <div class="actions">
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Join Now" class="btn btn-cta btn-cta-primary" data-disable-with="Join Now" />
      </div>
</form>  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer right_close_button">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the actual HTML that would include `#modal_new_user` ?  and "Unable to find visible field "Name" that is not disabled" does not mean that is sees the field "Name" but that it is disabled, It means it either  doesn't see the field or it does see the field but it is disabled - don't read more into the errror than it states.

Comment: This can be a timing issue. You have to remember that capybara starts clicking things at a blazing speed which is often before the JS has completed. Try using `find('#modal_new_user').fill_in('Name', with: 'Jo Blo')` as this will wait for the element to appear.

Comment: @max `fill_in` alone will wait for a matching element too (up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds) since it's implemented as `find(...).set(..)`

Comment: I have Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5.

Comment: I have added the code for the modal.

Comment: The errors you've reported would indicate the modal isn't showing up, but your claim of the screenshot showing up would contradict that - how/when are you generating the screenshot?

Comment: Thomas, I am using capybara-screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the test had `type: :system`, so when I removed this, the test passed. It appears there is an [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/30638) with rails system tests if puma.rb specified concurrency.